# Set OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory to MTP device

Tags: .net, openfiledialog, mtp

I am writing an app to get pictures off of a camera, and want to open an OpenFileDialog with its InitialDirectory set to be the camera.

This works fine:

```
openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\someFolder\\";
```

But these do not:

```
openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "CameraName\\";
openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "My Computer\\CameraName\\";
```

I assume it is because it is an MTP device, and that's not its "real directory name".  Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: MTP doesn't emulate a file system.  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=19153

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it is not possible to accomplish this, at least not with .NET IO operations, because MTP devices do not conform to basic I/O operations (read/write).

Here you have to either find some way to force map the MTP device storage with a drive letter (Seen a guy once trying to accomplish this, not sure where he got), or simply remove the SD card and connect it directly to the PC.

Sorry that I couldn't help you much.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and found [How to construct path for mtp devices (usable in folder browse dialog)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452798/how-to-construct-path-for-mtp-devices-usable-in-folder-browse-dialog)

When I insert `"{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"` (which there they say is "my computer") as `InitialDirectory`, it will actually show the MTP folder :)