# How to use ADB in a Batch file to open a Windows File Explorer window

Tags: android, batch-file, adb, windows-explorer

I'm trying to run a bat that will open a specified folder from an android device using ADB in Windows. For the life of me I have searched and hacked my way through to nowhere (my search skills are fairly weak, so sorry if this is a dupe).

I can easily do it on a Windows folder with START but that doesn't seem to work within the ADB command structure.

Thanks in advance.

```
adb devices -l 
for /f %%G in ('adb devices') do ( if not %%G==List ( adb -s %%G pull "/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.title/files/Logs" C:/Work/copied/ adb -s %%G pull "/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.title/files/FPS" C:/Work/copied/ echo %%G transfer complete. ) ) adb -s start "/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.title/files/FPS"
```

Comment: If you use your search the only one relevant that comes up is this question. None of the others are even remotely what I'm looking for.  This is why I posted the question as I was unable to find the answer. Something helpful vs snarky would be appreciated.

Comment: I can put up some code but none of it works in the least hence I'm asking the question.
```
adb -s %%G Start "/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.title/files/
```
Not really sure what you mean by too broad as to me it seems quite specific.

Comment: I assume `%%G` is a returned variable from a `for` loop you haven't provided, but what is it? and why would `Start` be part of that same command? You have obvioussly got some code, and certainly more than you've posted in the comment above. You need to provide us with a defined task, some code written to perform it, an issue it is exhibiting, any output and some debugging information. Please see [mcve]

Comment: You don't put any of that code into a comment, you put it into your question. What you do is use the [edit] button, and paste your code into your question, select/highlight it all, then click on the `{}` button to format it as code. Please do that and delete your comment above. Please also remember that I asked for output and debugging information, so make sure that `echo`ing is not off, and run the script from a Command Prompt window, so that the output can be copied and posted too!

Comment: I have deleted the comment and put the code above. Im not at my work computer till Monday so will try get the output for it then.

Comment: In order to run more than one command on the same line there has to be a method of informing the interpreter where one command ends and another one starts. There is absolutely no way that whatever `( if not %%G==List ( adb -s %%G pull "/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.title/files/Logs" C:/Work/copied/ adb -s %%G pull "/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.title/files/FPS" C:/Work/copied/ echo %%G transfer complete. ) ) adb -s start "/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.title/files/FPS"` means will ever work.

Comment: I can't add it to the question as I think I've marked it answered below: I was editing on my phone and it didn't put the return carriages in, they are on separate lines in the code. when running start it returns "adb.exe: unknown command start"

Answer (score 0):

For those who wish to do the same down the line, I have found something that works, its got a few messy steps at the start, but it works.

[How to construct path for mtp devices (usable in folder browse dialog)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452798/how-to-construct-path-for-mtp-devices-usable-in-folder-browse-dialog)

so I guess this can be marked as a dupe after all.